# ¿Como puedo cambiar autenticación login.microsoftonline.com IIS a login.live.com (Cuenta personal)?

Tags: iis

en mi app web IIS dice Inicia sesión con cuenta [profesional o educativa](https://login.microsoftonline.com/) y quiero que sea [personal](https://login.live.com/)

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda agregar lo que intentaste o investigaste, revisa [ask], edita tu pregunta y agrega màs informaciòn, saludos.

Comment: al crear salía Usar servidor de Autenticación De Microsoft no salía "Usar Login.Live" o "Usar Login.MSOnline" ni cosas asís ponía
```
Docker = false; HTTPS = true; SSLProtocol = [int.S:SLP]; autenticación Windows = false; Autenticación Microsoft = false; "login.live" = "desconocido"; "login.msonline" = "desconocido [sí]";```

Comment: te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)